# What is the most efficient way to parallelize python code that uses rpy2?

Tags: python, r, parallel-processing, rpy2, joblib

I am using python3 and in it, I use the `rpy2`package to access R, pass in R code where my heavy computation is done, and get results back to python. In particular, I am using the `lfe` function of R (documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/lfe.pdf)).

I would like to know which option is better: doing the parallelization in python or in R. Does it matter? Why should we suspect that one is more efficient than the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the exception of multi-threading (which is not a great way to parallelize Python code anyway because of the GIL), and this because R cannot handle concurrency, any other way to either parallelize Python tasks (you'll find reports of people using `rpy2` with `pyspark` and `multiprocessing`) or R (there are R packages for parallelization) will work.